# String Formatting: what is the width for the e format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

My IronPython console gives the following:

```
 >>> "%9.2e" % 1.236
 '1.24e+00'
 >>> "%10.2e" % 1.236
 ' 1.24e+00'
 >>>
```

The total characters in the output do not seem to correspond to 9 or 10 respectively.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on CPython 2.7.8. I get 9 and 10 characters, respectively. Conclusion: you found a bug in IronPython.

Comment: Can you try `format(1.236, '9.2e')` and `format(1.236, '10.2e')` as possible work-arounds?

Comment: Using the format method works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I gave up looking for the float `__format__` hook, so I couldn't verify that it'd use different code. The `StringFormatter` class used for `%` string formatting didn't look all that reusable though, so bets were on 'no code sharing' there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [know bug with IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/28936); the width is not handled correctly when using the `%<width>e` format.

CPython handles the width as expected; e.g. `'%9.2e' % 1.236` produces a string of length 9. You could try using the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) instead, if you are *lucky* it doesn't reuse the same code:

```
format(1.236, '9.2e')
```

Comment: My best guess is that this is the relevant source:  https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Runtime/Operations/StringOps.cs#L1369  (although I don't speak C# and have never looked at the source before . . .)

Comment: @mgilson: the actual formatting implementation is handled in the [`StringFormatter` class file](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Runtime/StringFormatter.cs). And there is a glimmer of hope here as the `str.format()` method and the `format()` function delegate formatting to the types themselves. Now to find the `float` implementation in that pile and see what the `__format__` method does, perhaps it does this with a separate implementation.

Comment: And here, for some silly reason, I thought that StringFormatter was a builtin :-).  I guess I've just gotten too used to python's namespaces.

Comment: @PawelJasinski: more bugs, yay!

Comment: @PawelJasinski: no, there is not.

Comment: @PawelJasinski: so the `format()` route rounds the value to a smaller precision. Single precision perhaps? Note that both samples in *CPython* produce more precision still.

Comment: @PawelJasinski: put those same two lines into a CPython prompt and you'll see more digits being printed.